# What is the difference between > and >> in bash

Tags: bash

Can anyone please explain me what's the difference between the following two statements ?

```
echo "my name is abc" > test.txt
echo "my name is abc" >> test.txt
```

Comment: Looks like bash (or similar) - not php. see http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: Where is `PHP` involved in the question? It looks like `unix shell` to me.

Comment: In PHP specifically, `>` is a greater than operator (used in comparisons) while `>>` is a bitwise shift operator.... both are described in this special feature of PHP called documentation

Comment: Voted to close as unclear what you're asking. It's probably reasonable to assume that this is from a shell script but it's up to the OP to clarify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one will set the file contents of test.txt to "my name is abc", the second one will append the string "my name is abc" to test.txt

`>` is the redirect operator, which redirects `stdout` to a file, overwriting the contents of the file.

`>>` is the redirect & append operator, which redirects `stdout` to a file, but in append mode.

This is shell scripting (bash probably), not PHP.